# jQuery Masked Input: How do I animate the appearance of the text?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/jPgOQO) (click on the input)

What I want to do is to add some kind of `opacity` on the appearing text with the `transition` applied to it. But looks like there are no classes or wrappers whatsoever and the plugin offers no API for that.

Any way I can make a smooth animation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS transition. Take a look here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJMoGj

```
input {
    color: #FFF;
}
input:focus {
    color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use CSS's rgba and jquery's css().

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpOKJp

I applied a css transition to input's color of 1s and a change in the input text color's opacity triggered by jquery's click():

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="fadein" value="test" />
```

CSS:

```
#fadein
{
    transition:color 1s;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
var opac=1;
$("#fadein").click(function()
                  {

    $("#fadein").css("color", "rgba(0,0,0,"+ opac +")");
    opac= 1-opac;
});
```

This approach is independent of background color.

Comment: it also loses the mask

Answer (score 1):

the opacity thing is easy enough the transition thing is harder, but you can fancy it up with a background transition maybe?

```
input{opacity:.4; }
input:focus{background-color: lightgreen;
  cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: transition all ease-out 1s;
    -moz-transition:transition all 2s ease-out 1s;
    -o-transition: transition all 2ms ease-out 1s;
    transition:transition all 2s ease-out 1s;}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbvWOp